# NSSearchField with tokenized search values

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nssearchfield, nstokenfieldcell

I am looking for a way to implement the search input with tokens like in mail apps to achieve a similar result:

[image]

I wonder if there is a straightforward way to implement it. I spent some time investigating if there is anything similar open sourced and found nothing. But the majority of mail clients have this kind of inputs, including the "recents" menu:

[image]

Is there any way to reuse NSTokenFieldCell to achieve the same result but in NSSearchField? Or should I just use NSTokenField, and append a search icon and a menu to it?